# ignore whitespace in regular expression for json response using java

Tags: java, regex

when performing a REST operation, the following element is available in the response, however i want to capture the value of json property, by ignoring the leading and trailing white spaces.

The response can be "bs_id":"1234"  or "bs_id" : "1234"  or "bs_id": "1234"

I need to capture the value of bs_id key ignore any pattern of white spaces.

how to accomplish that?

Comment: this is how i tried "\"bs_id\":\"(.+?)\"",   but sometimes the whitespaces appear before and after :  and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: the regex construct for matching whitespaces is `\s`. You should be able to construct it from that information (or pick up a basic regex tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
private static final Pattern BS_ID_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("\"bs_id\" *: *\"([^"]*)\"");

private String extractBsId(String jsonString) {
    Matcher bsIdMatcher = BS_ID_PATTERN.matcher(jsonString);
    if (bsIdMatcher.find()) {
        return bsIdMatcher.group(1);
    }
    // "bs_id" not found, so return null or an error as appropriate.
    return null;
}
```

This allows for any amount (zero or more, using the regex `*` matcher) of spaces before and/or after the colon, but if you only want to permit zero or one space you can replace the `*` matcher with the `?` matcher.

By the way, it's very common to see the regex shorthand `\s` used for matching whitespace, but be careful with this as it will match not only standard space characters but also newlines, carriage returns, tabs, and vertical tabs, and this is usually not what people really want.